# Binary divisibility by 10

Tags: binary, division

How to check if a binary number can be divided by 10 (decimal), without converting it to other system.
For example, we have a number:

```
1010 1011 0100 0001 0000 0100
```

How we can check that this number is divisible by 10?

Comment: Do you mean 10 decimal or 10 binary?

Comment: Every number (exuding 0) is divisible by 10

Comment: 10 decimal. I forgot to mention it in the post. Edit: post edited.

Comment: @asawyer: 0 is also divisible by 10.  0 / 10 = 0.  The other way around, 0 / 10, is undefined.  Of course, most of the time the result of the division is not a whole number :-)

Comment: @EricJ.  What I was trying to get at was that the question was ambiguously worded.

Comment: @asawyer actually, the strict mathmatical definition of `x` being divisable by `y` means there exists some integer `m` such that `ym = x` that is it is divided without remainder -- so it was not at all ambiguous. I can understand how it can be confusing since we perform division on non-divisable numbers all the time, i.e. we get a result with a remiander/ a decimal -- which make no sense if you are careful with the definition of the word divisable.

Comment: @Wooble: Been too long since I took a math class I guess.  Forgot that *divisible* has a strict definition in math ("evenly divided without remainder",   http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/divisible?s=t)

Answer (score 3):

> First split the number into odd and even bits (I'm calling "even" the
> bits corresponding to even powers of 2):
>
> 100100110010110000000101101110
> 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 even    1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1  odd
>
> Now in each of these, add and subtract the digits alternately, as in
> the standard test for divisibility by 11 in decimal (starting with
> addition at the right):
>
> 100100110010110000000101101110    +0-1+0-1+0-0+1-0+0-0+1-1+0-1+0 =
> -2   +1-0+0-1+0-1+1-0+0-0+0-0+1-1+1  =  1
>
> Now double the sum of the odd digits and add it to the sum of the even
> digits:
>
> 2*1 + -2 = 0
>
> If the result is divisible by 5, as in this case, the number itself is
> divisible by 5.
>
> Since this number is also divisible by 2 (the rightmost digit being
> 0), it is divisible by 10.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110144318/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55908.html)

Comment: I found this; I thought that somebody has found an easier solution, that's why I created this question. Anyway, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about computational methods, you can do a divisiblity-by-5 test and a divisibility-by-2 test.
The numbers below assume unsigned 32-bit arithmetic, but can easily be extended to larger numbers.

I'll provide some code first, followed by a more textual explanation:

```c
unsigned int div5exact(unsigned int n)
{
    // returns n/5 as long as n actually divides 5
    // (because 'n * (INV5 * 5)' == 'n * 1' mod 2^32

    #define INV5 0xcccccccd

    return n * INV5;

}

unsigned int divides5(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int q = div5exact(n);
    if (q <= 0x33333333) /* q*5 < 2^32? */
    {
        /* q*5 doesn't overflow, so n == q*5 */
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        /* q*5 overflows, so n != q*5 */
        return 0;
    }
}

int divides2(unsigned int n)
{
    /* easy divisibility by 2 test */
    return (n & 1) == 0;
}

int divides10(unsigned int n)
{
    return divides2(n) && divides5(n);
}


/* fast one-liner: */
#define DIVIDES10(n) ( ((n) & 1) == 0 && ((n) * 0xcccccccd) <= 0x33333333 )
```

Divisibility by 2 is easy: *(n&1) == 0* means that *n* is even.

Divisibility by 5 involves multiplying by the inverse of 5, which is 0xcccccccd (because *0xcccccccd * 5 == 0x400000001*, which is just 0x1 if you truncate to 32 bits).
When you multiply *n*5* by the inverse of 5, you get *n * 5*(inverse of 5)*, which in 32-bit math simplifies to *n*1* .

Now let's say *n* and *q* are 32-bit numbers, and *q = n*(inverse of 5) mod 2<sup>32</sup>*.
Because *n* is no greater than 0xffffffff, we know that *n/5* is no greater than *(2<sup>32</sup>-1)/5* (which is 0x33333333).  Therefore, we know if *q* is less than or equal to *(2<sup>32</sup>-1)/5*, then we know *n* divides exactly by 5, because *q * 5* doesn't get truncated in 32 bits, and is therefore equal to *n*, so *n* divides *q* and 5.

If *q* is greater than *(2<sup>32</sup>-1)/5*, then we know it doesn't divide 5, because there is a one-one mapping between the 32-bit numbers divisible by 5 and the numbers between 0 and *(2<sup>32</sup>-1)/5*, and so any number out of this range doesn't map to a number that's divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code in python to check the divisibilty by 10 using bitwise technique**

```
#taking input in string which is a binary number eg: 1010,1110
s = input()
#taking initial value of x as o
x = 0
for i in s:
    if i == '1':
        x = (x*2 + 1) % 10
    else:
        x = x*2 % 10
#if x is turn to be 0 then it is divisible by 10
if x:
print("Not divisible by 10")
else:
print("Divisible by 10")
```